# AWS Cognito dataset sync limits - What happens when you sync more than 1mb per set

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

AWS Cognito allows you to sync datasets across devices but the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/synchronizing-data.html) states:

```
Each dataset can have a maximum size of 1 MB. 
You can associate up to 20 datasets with an identity.
```

However it appears that if you **DO NOT** sync the datasets and simply keep them local then the dataset can be larger than 1mb in size.

What happens if you then try and sync those sets? is it that Cognito throws an error and simply doesn't allow it OR The dataset is trimmed to 1mb such that only the most recent records sync OR something else?

NOTE: I am aware that one could split data across multiple sets and then perform a sync but this is NOT a solution for me as I require all 20 sets already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito will throw an exception (LimitExceededException, if memory serves) when you have put more than 1 MB into a dataset. It won't truncate data and accept the synchronization request.

Comment: Have you confirmed that after throwing that exception cognito does not go on to sync anyway? I have been seeing strange behavior from cognito in that regard. It seems to sometimes sync anyway despite this exception and that leaves me wondering what happens on the AWS end exactly..

Comment: I work on the Cognito team and know that's the expected behavior. Can you elaborate on when you're seeing something else? Are you absolutely sure it's over 1 MB when that happens? If you are, could you give me a request id and a rough timestamp?

Comment: If you're sure that's the expected behavior then I'm probably doing something wrong in my code. Will investigate when I have time. For now i'll note your answer as correct

Comment: Sorry, I poorly worded that. I'm sure it's expected behavior to throw back an error, not accept the sync. If you're seeing otherwise, that merits an investigation.